# Android OpenGL circle(sphere) look like ellipse .. no projection/camera

Tags: android, opengl-es, geometry, ellipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZWx8.png)

> **also attached screen shot from the device, 
>   can u pls help me resolving the issue... 
>   its Android KitKat version**

```
public class Balloon
{
    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
            // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
                    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "gl_PointSize = 5.0;                  "+
                    "  gl_Position =  vPosition;" +
                    "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                    "}";

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final int mProgram;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    private float[] data = new float[126];

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;

    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 0.0f };

    /**
     * Sets up the drawing object data for use in an OpenGL ES context.
     */
    public Balloon() {

        // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
        int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             
        // create empty OpenGL Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   
        // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); 
        // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  
       // create OpenGL program executables

    }

    private void FillBalloon(float x1,float y1,float r1)
    {
        int i=0,j=0;
        float angle = 0;

        float twicePI = (float)2.0 * (float)3.1415926;


        float angle_stepsize = 0.1f;

        // go through all angles from 0 to 2 * PI radians
        for(;angle < twicePI;angle = (angle + angle_stepsize))
        {
            // calculate x, y from a vector with known length and angle
            data[j++] = x1 + r1 * (float)Math.cos(angle);
            data[j++] = y1 + r1 * (float)Math.sin(angle);

        }

        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                j * 4);
        // use the device hardware's native byte order
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        vertexBuffer.put(data);
        // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

    }


    /**
     * Encapsulates the OpenGL ES instructions for drawing this shape.
     *
     */
    public void draw() {
        // Add program to OpenGL environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        float posX = 0.0f,posY = 0.0f,radius =0.2f;

        FillBalloon(posX, posY, radius);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = 
                GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram,"vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the balloon coordinate data

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
        MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("mColorHandle");


        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 63);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }
}
```

also attached screen shot from the device, 
can u pls help me resolving the issue... 
its Android KitKat version

Answer (score 1):

To make the balloons look like circles, add an float (let's call it X_SCALE) as a parameter to draw:

```
public void draw(float X_SCALE) {
   ...
   FillBaloon(posX, posY, radius, X_SCALE);
   ...
}
```

Then multiply your draw-time x coordinate by that scale factor in FillBaloon(...):

```
data[j++] = x1 + X_SCALE * r1 * (float)Math.cos(angle);
```

And set the scale factor in your renderer draw ( X_SCALE) call:

```
X_SCALE = (float)MyGLSurfaceView.getHeight()/(float)MyGLSurfaceView.getWidth();
myBaloon.draw(X_SCALE);
```

Even better would be to set X_SCALE once in onSurfaceCreated ( ... ) and each time the surface is resized in onSurfaceChanged ( ... ) .

One last thing: you can avoid casting doubles as floats by using an "f" suffix in explicit initialization:

```
float twicePI = 6.28318530717959f;
```

Comment: This looks backwards to me. I think you want to use the inverse of the aspect ratio as the scaling factor. Or use this value to scale y, not x.

Comment: Thanks Reto Koradi, and Richard Klaassen... inverse of Aspect on X or Factor on Y works well... you ppl made my day... Thanks  a ton..

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. The default coordinate system for the openGL is [-1, 1] in every axis. That means that the left most point will have `x=-1`, rightmost `x=1`, topmost `y=1` and bottommost `y=-1`. Now depending on your screen ratio the result will have the same stretched ratio.

It is up to you to handle the scene to draw the shape as you please. One way is to scale the vertex data when generating them but I strongly discourage you to do so as the model vertex data should be as they are meant to be. Another way is to simply create a square surface view which then limits your drawing surface so it is not the best approach again. Yet another way is to use the viewport and set a rectangle within which you want to draw your shape in which may be ok but you need to remember to set it back to full width and height. And then there are matrices...

Use a matrix to define your coordinate system. For 2D the best method is usually to use `Ortho` which uses border parameters (left, top, bottom, right) which may then be set to whatever you want. For instance you may use view coordinates (`left = 0`, `right = viewWidth`, `top = 0`, `bottom = viewHeight`) or you could normalize the system around zero and choose which border should have a value of `1.0`: For horizontal normalization you will have (`left = -1`, `right = 1`, `top = viewHeight/viewWidth`, `bottom = -viewHeight/viewWidth`) and for vertical (`left = -viewWidth/viewHeight`, `right = viewWidth/viewHeight`, `top = 1.0`, `bottom = -1.0`).